# R creating a new column by reading the current row and the Previous row

Tags: r, data-analysis

I have a data frame that looks like this

> data

```
Category          start_time(need to fill)   
Low
Low
Low
Low
Below Normal
Below Normal
Low
Below Normal
Below Normal
Below Normal
```

I need to compare each row with its previous row ,and if the category changed 
i would fill the start_time variable of that row with a 1.ie

> If (Category (Row)!=Category( Previous  Row) Then Set Start_Time =1

so my finaldata set shoudl look some thing like this

```
Category    Start Time 
Low              1 //Initially set to 1 
Low              0
Low              0
Low              0
Below Normal     1
Below Normal     0
Low              1 
Below Normal     1 
Below Normal     0
Below Normal     0
```

Is there an easy way to do this in R.I am sure that i can do this without a FOR loop in R.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`).  From `v1.9.6`, `rleid` function was introduced, which will give a new grouping index whenever the current value is different from the previous one.  We use that as a grouping index, and use `rep` to replicate 1 and 0 for `times` 1 and the length of the group -1 (`.N-1`) for each group and assign (`:=`) the output to a new column.

```
library(data.table)#v.9.6+
 setDT(df1)[, StartTime :=rep(c(1,0), c(1L, .N-1)) , rleid(Category)]
```

Or this can be done more easily by just comparing the lag and lead of 'Category' to give a logical index, append with `TRUE` as the length will be one less than the nrow of 'df1' and wrap with `+` so that the logical index is coerced to binary.

```
setDT(df1)[,  StartTime := +c(TRUE,Category[-1L]!= Category[-.N])]
df1
#        Category StartTime
# 1:          Low         1
# 2:          Low         0
# 3:          Low         0
# 4:          Low         0
# 5: Below Normal         1
# 6: Below Normal         0
# 7:          Low         1
# 8: Below Normal         1
# 9: Below Normal         0
#10: Below Normal         0
```

Comment: Wow!!!That was beautiful.Thanks dude..Worked perfectly..Could you share some insights also about your code.I am in learning phase .Thanks !